# Loading/ feed_dicting large dataset into Tensorflow session

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, computer-vision, large-data

I am trying to consume 50k image dataset for a convNet in ratio tr-60%, test-20%, validate-20%. 
So far I have created  a placeholder and feed_dicting it @ sess.run(), as follows:-

```
tf_train_dataset = tf.placeholder(
    tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, image_size, image_size, num_channels))
......
...
feed_dict = {tf_train_dataset : batch_data, tf_train_labels : batch_labels}
    _, l, predictions = session.run(
      [optimizer, loss, train_prediction], feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

but according to official TF performance guide it is a poor way to implement, as follows:-
[link to TF guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide)

> Unless for a special circumstance or for example code, do not feed
>   data into the session from Python variables, e.g. dictionary.
>
> ```
> # This will result in poor performance.
> sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
> ```

Can you please help in implementing queues for reading data in TF?

One way I found is :-

> Create an op which is loading your data in stream fashion

But I am not sure 
**1)** if it is best way, 
**2)** I couldn't implement above suggestion, can you help in creating this op pseudo code?
Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is generally a bad idea to feed data using feed_dict but you don't always have to write ops to process your data. You can convert your image data to the format that tensorflow can recognize: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/how_tos/reading_data/convert_to_records.py. This process can be made in parallel and you can output a list of files since tensorflow can consume file list as well.

Then follow the tutorial on this page to create queues and feed data in python: https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data